How can I get the number of displayed options in MUIs Autocomplete?
I'm trying to get the number of displayed options after filtering in MUIs Autocomplete component. I.e. after the user types something inside the input, the component shows the filtered results; how can I find out how many results are being shown?
My best attempt was to use the filterOptions prop:
import MuiAutocomplete, {
  createFilterOptions,
} from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";

const filter = createFilterOptions();

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [filteredOptionsCount, setFilteredOptionsCount] = useState();

  return (
    <MuiAutocomplete
      filterOptions={(optionsList, state) => {
        const filteredOptions = filter(optionsList, state);

        setFilteredOptionsCount(filteredOptions.length);

        return filteredOptions;
      }}
    />
  );
};

And it seems to work fine but for some reason setting the state inside this function yields a warning like this:

Cannot update a component while rendering a different component.

Is there any alternative for doing this without causing any warnings?

The warning occurs because you're calling setFilteredOptionsCount during the rendering process of a different component.
Instead of using filterOptions prop, You should be using onInputChange to get the count of filtered options. Check the example below 
import Autocomplete, { createFilterOptions } from '@mui/material/Autocomplete'
import { useState } from 'react'

const filter = createFilterOptions()

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  return (
     <Autocomplete
       options={myOptions}
       renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="My Input" />}
       onInputChange={(_, value) => {
           const filteredOptions = filter(myOptions, { inputValue: value, getOptionLabel: (option) => option.label })
           setCount(filteredOptions.length)
       }}
     />
   )
}

